# How to match and fetch date from timestamp array in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have folders named as **timestamp_string** in a folder named as users. e.g.

> folder1 = ts1_str1,
>   folder2 = ts2_str2, folder 3 = ts3_str3, folder4 = ts4_str2

and these all folders in a folder named as users. 
 I want to search folder using date and string as you can see I have used in my code i.e. 26/8/2016 and str2. I am using the following code for my solution:

```
var search_date = '26/8/2016';
var search_str  = 'str2';

fs.readdirSync(dirpath+'/users').forEach(function (folder) {

  var folderName1  = folder.split('_');

  var folderName = folderName1[0]; // 1472198068898 i.e. timestamp

  var strName = folderName1[1]; // str1 or str2 etc.

  var d  = new Date(parseInt(folderName));

  if((search_date == d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear()) && (search_str == strName))
  {
     matchArr.push('**what should be here so that i can create array of those folders which have date 26/8/2016 in their timestamp ???** ');
  }

});
```

I only need help in my **matchArr** creation, i.e. what should I use so that I can get array of those folders which are created on 26/8/2016 and have string name as str2. Please let me know if you have any query?

Thank you!

Comment: `var matchArr = []; /* ... */  matchArr.push(folder)` ?

Comment: yes those folders which match the conditions.

Comment: what is your problem? the if condition does not work?

Comment: no condition is working, I got my answer, writting that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer as written there.

```
fs.readdirSync(APPDATApath+'/foldername/users/1').forEach(function (folder) {

 folderName1  = folder.split('_');

 folderName = folderName1[0];

 var strName = folderName1[1]; // str1 or str2 etc.

 var d  = new Date(parseInt(folderName));

 if((search_date == d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear()) && (string_name == strName))
 {

   matchArr.push(folderName+'_'+strName); // this is what I am looking for
 }

});
```

now I am getting array of those folders name which meets the condition in all folders names.